# JQuery Supersized portrait photos display stretched

Tags: jquery, css, supersized

i am trying to make a photo gallery for a friend and i am relying on supersized.js and so far it has worked great , but now im having this weird problem with vertical photos loading in some sort of full screen width and when it loads it displays correctly, i think i may having a problem with CSS, i've tried setting the li element that contain the img to a max width but it didnt work.

The website is  http://www.fernandolandin.com

any hints on what may be causing this problem?

Comment: are you using image pre-loading? This might help speed up the display times, and may solve the problem at the same time. Try also setting a max-height instead of max-width, to your images.

Comment: finally preloading images made it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

use the following code for `img` tag

```
<img src="http://www.fernandolandin.com/img/01.jpg" style="width: 100% !important; left: 0px; top: -237.5px; height: 100% !important;">
```

changed value `width: 100% !important`
and `height: 100% !important;`

important is needed as on screen re size the js is adding a width to the img. keep it `100% !important` so that it fits the screen. Try and let me know.

Comment: Actually width wise some images are looking stretched because of the default width